# ubuntu operating system apt-get upate command is giving me error

Tags: ubuntu-15.04

In my Ubuntu VERSION 15.04 operating system whenever I fire the command "sudo apt-get update" I have the error below as:

> "W: Failed to fetch
>   http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]"

Please help  me i am not able to do solve this issue.

Comment: what's inside */etc/apt/sources.list*?

Comment: sorry i didnt get u

Comment: Sorry sometimes my english (i’m italian pizza pasta e mandolino) doesn’t work correctly , post what print the command *cat /etc/apt/source.list*